# Google Cloud Messaging No authentication challenges found error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

**Problem**

I keep getting a "No authentication challenges found" IOException error when I try to send a Google Cloud Messaging message.

**What**

I am trying to send the message from an Android phone using the gcm-server.jar file in the GCM SDK package.  I based my code off the server example in the GCM documentation.

```
Sender sender = new Sender(MyProjectId);
Builder message = new Message.Builder();
message.collapseKey("test");
message.addData("test", "42");
Message data = message.build();
Result result = null;
try {
    result = sender.send(data, deviceID, 5);
} catch(IOException e) {
    Log.e("GCM Error", e.getMessage());
}
```

**Other Info**

I am trying to send push messages from device to device without the need of a "third party" server to get involved.  I am not sure if it is even possible to use an Android phone to push out messages through GCM.

Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like my code was not wrong.  I was using the wrong API id from my apis account.  Everything is working now.

Comment: Solve : I have use the default api key and it work for me also :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use deafult api key under tag **Key for browser apps (with referers)** from Google Api Console

```
Sender sender = new Sender(defaultApiKey);
```